# Textview can't be displayed on exoplayer videoview

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make textview display on videoview，but the videoview is overwriting textview
This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:useDefaultControls="false"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and this is my mainactivity code

```
val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.video_test)
                    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("${Source_add}"))
                    videoView.start()
```

Comment: Put the textview code underneath the videoview code

Answer (score 0):

Place your textview code below the videoview code. Framelayout works on overlapping way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **translationZ**

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Test"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:useDefaultControls="false"/>
</FrameLayout>
```